# Extract Optimal Parameters from Flexmix: Univariate Data

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate a table in the book [HMM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584885734):

[image]

Specifically, the k=2 model.

I am using the code:

```
dat<-as.data.frame(c(13,  8,  23,   22, 18, 15, 14, 11, 24, 18, 14, 16, 8,  14, 27, 15, 10, 13, 10, 23, 41, 20, 15, 15, 16, 18, 31, 15, 8,  16, 26, 17, 27, 22, 15, 11, 32, 19, 35, 19, 6,  11, 27, 20, 26, 16, 11, 18, 22, 28, 30, 8,  32, 19, 36, 27, 7,  36, 13, 39, 29, 18, 24, 26, 21, 23, 16, 22, 13, 17, 20, 13, 23, 14, 22, 16, 12, 22, 22, 17, 21, 13, 18, 24, 19, 21, 20, 25, 21, 15, 25, 15, 21, 22, 34, 16, 16, 21, 26, 10, 18, 12, 14, 21, 15, 15, 18))
colnames(dat)<-"x"

x2 <- flexmix(x~1, data=dat, k=2,model=FLXMRglm(formula=x~1,family="poisson"))
summary(x2)
```

Examining the priors and the log lik it appears the syntax is doing what I want :). My question is how to extract the component means lambda (15.777 and 26.840 above)? I do not believe they are simply the mean value of the data in each cluster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
exp(parameters(x2))
```

You can use `parameters` to extract the coefficients but the model defaults to using a log link-function so you need to use `exp` to convert back to the original scale.